# Is it possible to control the speed of a hoverboard motor[BLDC motor] with a raspberry pi? If so, how?

Tags: raspberry-pi, brushless-motor

In my project, I'm making a robot using two hover board motors, a motor control board such as this one:
https://www.ebay.com/p/2242827374?iid=162674407600
and a raspberry pi. I've connected the motor to the motor controller board, and the motor controller board to the motor. The motors work fine, I can run a function that makes the motors spin forward or backward. The one problem is the speed. I read that a pin on the motor controller board[VR pin] controls the speed. When running the motor, it is meant to simply take a parameter that controls the speed of the motor. However the motor only runs at max speed regardless of what number I use in the parameter. Thank you in advance and let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you!

Comment: It's not clear if this motor driver takes a servo kind of PWM (a pulse between 1ms and 2ms with a 50hz frequency) or if it takes a duty cycle.  Can you download the datasheet for this board and paste the link here then we can provide more help.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an electronic speed controller. Be careful to check that the one you purchase supports forward AND reverse if you need both directions, and that they're rated for the voltage and current that you need.

The electronic speed controllers should take a PWM signal, but also you can check the datasheet for specifics.